# search Apple Notes -> jump or highlight position where match search term in note

Tags: spotlight, search, notes.app

I search all my notes for "fix". Apple Notes shows all notes where "fix" is matched.

[image]

When I click on one match "19/06/16 Howto fix replicati..." I have problems finding the term fix in this big note document. Some of my notes about 2000 lines.

Is there some jump to result or highlight result?

Comment: Search the document again, the same way you did the first time round.

The text indexer in Mac OS X is very good.

Comment: @OzzieSpin i dont know how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drag down at the home screen, when the search bar comes down, enter the word you would like to search for, and it will come up in the search results.